# How could one solve $\int_{0}^{\beta}\frac{e^{-2^{C_{0}}\zeta x}e^{-\frac{\tau x}{\beta -x}}}{x+\sigma}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I'm doing my thesis on a math-heavy topic (Telecommunication engineering ftw) and got stuck with this integral: $\mathbf{\mathcal{R}_{1}}=\int_{0}^{\beta}\frac{e^{-2^{C_{0}}\zeta x}e^{-\frac{\tau x}{\beta -x}}}{x+\sigma}dx$

Is there any clue? I have an intuition that the result will be something that has Ei(x) in it.

p.s: I have rewritten the integral into  more readable format (grouped constants)

$\int_{0}^{\beta}\frac{e^{-A x}e^{-\frac{\tau x}{\beta -x}}}{x+\sigma}dx$

Comment: can you explain the ${C_0}_{\zeta_{x}}$?

Comment: ah $-2^{C_{0}}\zeta x $ is just a constant$-2^{C_{0}}\zeta $ multiplied by x

Comment: $$
\int_0^\beta \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-ax}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\tau x}{\beta-x}}}{x+\sigma}
$$Is better for people to try and solve.

Comment: What makes you think this can be put into a closed form solution?

Comment: My instructor said he has solved it into closed-form with the hint: Ei(x) appeared in the result. :(

Comment: Your question is uncomplete because there is nothing said about the value ranges of the constants. E.g. $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{e^{-x+x/(1-x)}}{x+1} dx$ is divergent. So: All constants should be positive ?